# I can't establish a connection through Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I'm a newbie in using Tor so I've tried to establish a Tor network connection but it's obviously facing a problem. I tried to connect directly, w/o using bridges, but it failed. Then I've looked up the problem and I found some were saying that I should use a VPN, which I did and it failed as well. I tried using VPN along with building a bridge around my ISP, in case my ISP was blocking Tor Services, and of course it failed again. And I ain't using any local proxies. 
What can I do to solve this dilemma?

Comment: Can you please update your question to include some log output from Tor? Without it we have no real basis with which to recommend solutions. Redact any bridge addresses you may have obtained, please.